# How to apply fixup to fixup in git?

Tags: git

### Situation

I have 2 commits: first when I added a feature, a second where I fixed something and commited it with git fixup. So `git log -2` looks like this

```
commit efgh
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx
    fixup! Add sth

commit abcd
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx
    Add sth
```

### Main question

I want to add more fixes, which commit hash should I use in the fixup?

```
(a)  git commit --fixup abcd
(b)  git commit --fixup efgh
```

### My thinking and additional question

Option (b) seems a bad idea --- when doing a rebase with autosquash, the fixup `efgh` will be applied on the first commit `abcd`, so `efgh` will not exist anymore when next fixup (that I am about to do) is going to be applied. Is my thinking correct?

But option (a) is also not ideal, as logically I am fixing (in my particular case, not in general) something that I wrote in the fixup, so attaching it to `abcd` is counterintuitive.

Comment: AFAIK either approach will work.  In any case it's not difficult to test.

Answer (score 1):

As [snakecharmerb said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068533/how-to-apply-fixup-to-fixup-in-git#comment129051209_73068533), both methods work—but I would say that you're better off fixing up the fixup commit.

(It's also easy to hit the right one with `git commit --fixup "HEAD^/{Add sth}"` or `git commit --fixup ":/Add sth"`.  I find it easier to cut and paste a hash ID from `git log` though, not that I use `--fixup` often.)

What you see in `git log` when you use `--fixup` is simple enough: Git makes a commit whose commit message has the form `fixup! subject`.  That's what your commit `efgh` shows, for instance.  (Note: `abcd` is a valid abbreviated hash ID, but `efgh` is not, as the letters and digits here are from [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) notation: the hash ID of a commit is simply a number, normally expressed in hexadecimal, and often abbreviated to about 7 characters.  Anything that is at least 4 valid hexadecimal characters counts; the full length of a SHA-1 hash is 40 characters, and the full length of a SHA-256 hash is 64 characters.)

If you run:

```
git commit --fixup abcd
```

again, you'll get yet another commit with the exact same commit message as your `efgh`.  If you run:

```
git commit --fixup efgh
```

you'll get one whose message is `fixup! fixup! Add sth`.

When you actually run `git rebase --autosquash` later, here's how the mechanism works in Git:

- The rebase code enumerates all the commits to be copied, initially using `--topo-order` (see the `git rev-list` and/or `git log` manuals).
- The rebase code then uses the interactive *machinery*—something Git calls the *sequencer*.  In older Git versions, this is a special case; in modern Git, rebase uses the sequencer by default anyway, so nothing special happens at this point.
- But now that Git is using the sequencer, Git has an (internal) "instruction sheet" consisting of `pick` commands.  This is the instruction sheet that you get to see and edit when you use `git rebase --interactive`.

As the documentation says, this interactive (sequencer-based) rebase sheet looks like this:

```
pick deadbee The oneline of this commit
pick fa1afe1 The oneline of the next commit
...
```

What `--autosquash` does is to modify this sheet even before you get a chance to edit it.  The code starts by looking for commits whose message begins with `fixup!` or `squash!`.  Having found such a commit, the code then:

- finds a commit that matches this message (and this found commit must come *before* the current commit, that is to be moved in the sheet);
- places *this* commit right after that commit, in the sheet; and
- replaces `pick` with `fixup` or `squash`.

The actual wording in the documentation goes on to mention that hash IDs will be used as well; this is a quote from the Git 2.37 documentation:

> `--autosquash`, `--no-autosquash`
>       When the commit log message
> begins with "squash! ..." or "fixup! ..." or "amend! ...", and there
> is already a commit in the todo list that matches the same `...`,
> automatically modify the todo list of `rebase -i` so that the commit
> marked for squashing comes right after the commit to be modified,
> and change the action of the moved commit from `pick` to `squash`
> or `fixup` or `fixup -C` respectively. A commit matches the `...`
> if the commit subject matches, or if the `...` refers to the
> commit’s hash. As a fall-back, partial matches of the commit
> subject work, too. The recommended way to create fixup/amend/squash
> commits is by using the `--fixup`, `--fixup=amend:` or
> `--fixup=reword:` and `--squash` options respectively of
> [git-commit[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

(The amend and reword options are new in Git 2.32.)

Testing shows that if you have two or more commits that both `fixup!` the *same subject*, Git puts the fixups in "topo order"—that is, the second fixup applies after the first fixup, not before it.  (This is what we want.)  But if you have `fixup! fixup! ...`, the documentation's wording would *force* Git to put them in topo order, because the second fixup has to match a commit whose subject now starts with one `fixup!`.  This is why I would recommend fixing up the fixup commit.